# Interface array forwarding and modports

Tags: system-verilog

### QUESTION

Are interface parameters for a module automatically deducted from the interface instance that is connected to the module instance?

### Background

I am designing a System that provides a communication infrastructure with multiple channels. Each channel can be tied to a different module by the user. To separate the user logic from the system I created a module wrapping the infrastructure. This is the setup in (pseudo) code

```
interface channel_if #(parameter int CHANNELBITS = 8);
     logic dummy;

     modport arbiter(input dummy);
endinterface

module arbiter(
    channel_if.arbiter channel[CHANNELS] //MODPORT defined
);
endmodule

module infrastructure(
    channel_if #(CHANNELBITS=16) channel[CHANNELS] //PARAMETERS defined
);

arbiter channelArbiter(channel);

endmodule
```

The problem I have is the following: I can either specify the parameters for the interface array ***OR*** the modport. I found no way (Vivado 2015.1) to define both, parameters *AND* modport.

In `top` the following code would be found:

...
channel_if #(CHANNELBITS=16) channelHarness[CHANNELS];
channel_if channelHarness[CHANNELS]; //either this or previous

infrastructure(.channel(channelHarness.arbiter));
...

While it is no problem to assign `InterfaceArray.modport` to the `infrastructure` module, I can not assign `InterfaceArray.modport` inside infrastructure (We already stripped the interface array down to modports at the infrastructure module boundary).

### Questions

Since I can not define the interfaceparameters  for arbiter (only possible if I do not define the modport, which yields inout orts for the interfac,e which I do not want), can I use Interfaces with non defaultparameters?

Are interface parameters for a module automatically deducted from the interface instance that is connected to the modelinstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter values are deduced from the interface instance that is connected to the model instance. See the example in section *25.8 Parameterized interfaces* of the 1800-2012 LRM.

The interface/modport construct in the SystemVerilog language is one of the most poorly documented sections of the LRM and has many [open issues](https://accellera.mantishub.com/view.php?id=2318). I would avoid using them unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I will read this, as "there is no way to specify both explicitly". It is a shame that interfaces are so "buggy", since they were one of sstem verilog strongpoints, leading me to try out system verilog.